# PhoneGap - JSON Data storing locally on the device

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am experimenting with PhoneGap and Android.

Does anyone have an example that shows how to store JSON data from an external site on a 
html5 WEBSQL database in an html file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PhoneGap Web SQL Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

[PhoneGap JSON Consumption](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/32513809/Simple-Web-Service-Consumption-with-PhoneGap-and-XUI)

[Building Android Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/), this book utilizes PhoneGap & JSON for a complete application

Answer (score 0):

another library which treats json beautifully for all kinds of local storage, websql indexdb etc is 
http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/